# Ajax form not showing html

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have an ajax based feedback form and having problems with the form showing the html from the response.

The Jquery code is

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var form_holder = $('#form-holder');
var form_holder_feedback = '';
$('.submit button').click(function() {
    var name = $('[name=name]').val();
    var email = $('[name=email]').val();
    var message = $('[name=message]').val();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'email/email.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {name: name, email: email, message: message},
        dataType: 'html',
    })
    .success(function(html) {
        form_holder_feedback = html;
        console.log(form_holder_feedback);
    })
    .error(function(html) {
        form_holder_feedback = '<strong>There was an error!</strong>';
    })

    form_holder.animate({
        'marginLeft': '840px'
    },300,'swing', function() {
        form_holder.css({
            'display'    : 'none',
            'margin-left': '0'
        }).html(form_holder_feedback).fadeIn('slow');
    });
});

});
```

What happens is the form sends the data and the data gets processed and the email gets sent. but the html echoed by the php email file is not showing up.

I have added the `console.log(form_holder_feedback);` to test the value after sending the form and it comes back with the line that is echoed by the php emailer.

Comment: try assigning static text in .html("Static Text goes here") and see if it is changing the text of the div. If you don't get it there it means there is some error in form_holder.animate({... block

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Show your `form_holder` after your ajax is complete

```
.success(function(html) {
        form_holder_feedback = html;
        console.log(form_holder_feedback);
        showFeedback(form_holder_feedback);
});
```

put code inside a function -

```
function showFeedback(fb){
    form_holder.animate({
        'marginLeft': '840px'
    },300,'swing', function() {
        form_holder.css({
            'display'    : 'none',
            'margin-left': '0'
        }).html(fb).fadeIn('slow');
    });
}
```

Comment: Yes this works however there is a bit of code duplication. Thanks though.

Answer (score 2):

Your callbacks (that set `form_holder_feedback`) are being executed after your `.html` call on `form_holder`. You'll need to put that code in the callbacks. To save yourself some code duplication, you should probably put it in a function.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var form_holder = $('#form-holder');
    var form_holder_feedback = '';
    var animateForm = function() {
        form_holder.animate({
            'marginLeft': '840px'
        },300,'swing', function() {
            form_holder.css({
                'display'    : 'none',
                'margin-left': '0'
            }).html(form_holder_feedback).fadeIn('slow');
        });
    }

    $('.submit button').click(function() {
        var name = $('[name=name]').val();
        var email = $('[name=email]').val();
        var message = $('[name=message]').val();

        $.ajax({
            url: 'email/email.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {name: name, email: email, message: message},
            dataType: 'html',
        })
        .success(function(html) {
            form_holder_feedback = html;
            animateForm();
        })
        .error(function(html) {
            form_holder_feedback = '<strong>There was an error!</strong>';
            animateForm();
        })
    });
});
```